# React Native Re-architecture Vs Flutter Performance Comparison

Tags: react-native, flutter

React Native Team is working on a new architecture which will eventually result in increase in react native performance but my Question is that **will it be able to compete with Flutter (Performance Wise)**?

[image: React Native New Architecture]

Comment: this seems like it should be a [github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter)